# How to link SonarQube with JIRA for the version 5.6

Tags: sonarqube, jira-plugin

I would like to link sonarQube - 5.6 with the JIRA to increase the Code Quality Standard. But in some blogs I could see like JIRA plugin has not been available for the version 5.6 -- > (**http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Version+Matrix**) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JIRA plugin has been deprecated.

To understand why it is not supported it any longer, please read the ["Stop planning; fix the leak!" blog post](https://blog.sonarsource.com/stop-planning-fix-the-leak/).